# unable to start activity from a service class in Android ( java.lang.NullPointerException )

Tags: android

I have a service which i use to parse xml data (with sax) after what i want to start an activity to show the data parsed using an intent. But every time i launch the activity my service crashes, so i removed the intent and put a toast instead==> the service works fine. But i really need to start the activity from the service to make a query with xml rpc.  My little finger tells me that it has something to do with context but i don't know anything about context.

Here is my service: (the problem lies with the intent1)

```
 package tfe.rma.ciss.be;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ParseFunction  extends Service{
    Server monServer;
    public String streamTitle = "",path="";
    public void onCreate() {

        Log.d("ParseFunction", ">>>onCreate()");

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart (Intent intent, int startId) {
        Log.d("ParseFunction", ">>>Started()"); 
        if (!mydata.equals("")){
         try {

             // URL rssUrl = new URL("http://thibault-koprowski.fr/feed");
              SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
              SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
              XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();
              RSSHandler myRSSHandler = new RSSHandler();
              myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);
              InputSource input = new InputSource(new StringReader(monServer.myData));
              myXMLReader.parse(input);
              Log.d("ParseFunction", ">>>my data is parsed()" + streamTitle );

             } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                 Log.d("ParseFunction", ">>>exception()");  
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
              Log.d("ParseFunction", ">>>exception()");
             } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
              Log.d("ParseFunction", ">>>exception()");
             } catch (SAXException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
              Log.d("ParseFunction", ">>>exception()");
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 Log.d("ParseFunction", ">>>exception()");
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();

             }
        }
        else {}
        if (!streamTitle.equals("")) {
            Log.d("ParseFunction", ">>>splitting streamTitle"); 
            try {
             String delims = "[\n]+" ;
                String[] tokens = streamTitle.split(delims) ;
                path= tokens[1];
                Log.d("ParseFunction", ">>>splitting done");

                Toast.makeText(this,path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
            catch (Exception z) {
                Log.d("ParseFunction", ">>>splitting error" + " " + z); 

            }
        } else 
        { path="n'a pas pu parser" + "/n" + "no path found"; }

        try {

            Log.d("ParseFunction", ">>>lauching activity test but ...." );
        Intent intent1= new Intent (this, Test.class);
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);



        startActivity(intent1); } catch (Exception z) {

            Log.d("ParseFunction", ">>>Activity said hell no, to screw myself " + z);

        }


    }
    private class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler
      {
       final int stateUnknown = 0;
       final int stateTitle = 1;
       int state = stateUnknown;

       int numberOfTitle = 0;
       String strTitle = "";
       String strElement = "";

     @Override
     public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }

     @Override
     public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      streamTitle =  strTitle;
     }

     @Override
     public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
       Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("sensorType"))
      {
       state = stateTitle;
       strElement = "";
       numberOfTitle++;
      }
      else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("imagePath"))
      {
       state = stateTitle;
       strElement = "";
       numberOfTitle++;
      }
      else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("numThreats"))
      {
       state = stateTitle;
       strElement = "";
       numberOfTitle++;
      }

      else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("latitude"))
      {
       state = stateTitle;
       strElement = "";
       numberOfTitle++;
      }
      else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("longitude"))
      {
       state = stateTitle;
       strElement = "";
       numberOfTitle++;
      }
      else
      {
       state = stateUnknown;
      }
     }

     @Override
     public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
       throws SAXException {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("sensorType"))
      {
       strTitle += strElement + "\n";
      }
      else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("imagePath"))
      {
       strTitle += strElement + "\n";
      }
      else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("numThreats"))
      {
       strTitle += strElement + "\n";
      }

      else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("latitude"))
      {
       strTitle += strElement + "\n";
      }
      else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("longitude"))
      {
       strTitle += strElement + "\n";
      }

      else {
      state = stateUnknown;}
     }

     @Override
     public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
       throws SAXException {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      String strCharacters = new String(ch, start, length);
      if (state == stateTitle)
      {
       strElement += strCharacters;
      }
     }

      }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
     public static String mydata = "<AvailableImageMsg><imageData><imageId>1234</imageId><sensorType>2</sensorType><imagePath>http://localhost/some/path</imagePath><timeStamp>2011-10-12T12:36:20</timeStamp></imageData><numThreats>3</numThreats><threatList><ThreadPixelDataType><threatData><threatId>3456</threatId><latitude>50.1234</latitude><longitude>4.5678</longitude><altitude>10.1</altitude><threatType>pepe</threatType><timestamp>2011-10-12T12:36:20</timestamp><threatLevel>70</threatLevel></threatData><Rectangle><PixelCoordinatesType><x>100</x><y>200</y></PixelCoordinatesType><PixelCoordinatesType><x>100</x><y>200</y></PixelCoordinatesType><PixelCoordinatesType><x>100</x><y>200</y></PixelCoordinatesType><PixelCoordinatesType><x>100</x><y>200</y></PixelCoordinatesType></Rectangle></ThreadPixelDataType></threatList><threatList><ThreadPixelDataType><threatData><threatId>3457</threatId><latitude>50.1234</latitude><longitude>4.5678</longitude><altitude>10.1</altitude><threatType>pepe</threatType><timestamp>2011-10-12T12:36:20</timestamp><threatLevel>70</threatLevel></threatData><Rectangle><PixelCoordinatesType><x>100</x><y>200</y></PixelCoordinatesType><PixelCoordinatesType><x>100</x><y>200</y></PixelCoordinatesType><PixelCoordinatesType><x>100</x><y>200</y></PixelCoordinatesType><PixelCoordinatesType><x>100</x><y>200</y></PixelCoordinatesType></Rectangle></ThreadPixelDataType></threatList><threatList><ThreadPixelDataType><threatData><threatId>3458</threatId><latitude>50.1234</latitude><longitude>4.5678</longitude><altitude>10.1</altitude><threatType>pepe</threatType><timestamp>2011-10-12T12:36:20</timestamp><threatLevel>70</threatLevel></threatData><Rectangle><PixelCoordinatesType><x>100</x><y>200</y></PixelCoordinatesType><PixelCoordinatesType><x>100</x><y>200</y></PixelCoordinatesType><PixelCoordinatesType><x>100</x><y>200</y></PixelCoordinatesType><PixelCoordinatesType><x>100</x><y>200</y></PixelCoordinatesType></Rectangle></ThreadPixelDataType></threatList></AvailableImageMsg>";


}
```

**Here is my simple activity named test**

```
package tfe.rma.ciss.be;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Test extends Activity{

    ParseFunction parser; 

    @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.test);

          TextView result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);




          result.setText(parser.path);}



}
```

can someone help me please?????!

**Logcat report**

```
01-12 13:42:18.069 I/ActivityManager(  160): Start proc tfe.rma.ciss.be for service tfe.rma.ciss.be/.ParseFunction: pid=1576 uid=10065 gids={3003, 1015}
01-12 13:42:18.189 D/ParseFunction( 1576): >>>onCreate()
01-12 13:42:18.189 D/ParseFunction( 1576): >>>Started()
01-12 13:42:18.189 D/AndroidRuntime( 1576): Shutting down VM
01-12 13:42:18.189 W/dalvikvm( 1576): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
01-12 13:42:18.199 E/        (  160): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
01-12 13:42:18.199 E/AndroidRuntime( 1576): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 13:42:18.199 E/AndroidRuntime( 1576): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service tfe.rma.ciss.be.ParseFunction@4051ecc8 with Intent { cmp=tfe.rma.ciss.be/.ParseFunction }: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-12 13:42:18.199 E/AndroidRuntime( 1576):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2056)
01-12 13:42:18.199 E/AndroidRuntime( 1576):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-12 13:42:18.199 E/AndroidRuntime( 1576):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:998)
01-12 13:42:18.199 E/AndroidRuntime( 1576):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-12 13:42:18.199 E/AndroidRuntime( 1576):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-12 13:42:18.199 E/AndroidRuntime( 1576):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-12 13:42:18.199 E/AndroidRuntime( 1576):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 13:42:18.199 E/AndroidRuntime( 1576):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-12 13:42:18.199 E/AndroidRuntime( 1576):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
01-12 13:42:18.199 E/AndroidRuntime( 1576):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
01-12 13:42:18.199 E/AndroidRuntime( 1576):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 13:42:18.199 E/AndroidRuntime( 1576): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-12 13:42:18.199 E/AndroidRuntime( 1576):     at tfe.rma.ciss.be.ParseFunction.onStart(ParseFunction.java:45)
01-12 13:42:18.199 E/AndroidRuntime( 1576):     at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:428)
01-12 13:42:18.199 E/AndroidRuntime( 1576):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2043)
01-12 13:42:18.199 E/AndroidRuntime( 1576):     ... 10 more
01-12 13:42:20.709 D/BatteryService(  160): update start
01-12 13:42:20.709 D/BatteryService(  160): update start
01-12 13:42:20.709 D/BatteryService(  160): update start
01-12 13:42:22.079 D/VoldCmdListener(   87): asec list
01-12 13:42:22.089 D/VoldCmdListener(   87): CommandListener::AsecCmd::runCommand -> com.aldiko.android-1
01-12 13:42:22.089 D/VoldCmdListener(   87): CommandListener::AsecCmd::runCommand -> com.citc.ud-1
01-12 13:42:22.089 D/VoldCmdListener(   87): CommandListener::AsecCmd::runCommand -> com.creativemobile.DragRacing-1
```

Comment: Post the exception stacktrace.

Comment: Have you added your activity to the application's AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: yep i did it and when i laucnh the application outside of the service, it works (of course with a static text)

Comment: The log says caused by NPE in line 45. That is where you create the InputSource. Could it be that you somehow removed the initialization of monServer? monServer.myData seems to be the culprit.

Comment: yeah, that was the problem for the null pointer excetpion. I've changed the server.myDat to anx static xml string  and the activity ... the activitiy launches now.. the only problem is that path is null. Thx a lot Dude :-)))))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent intent1= new Intent (this, Test.class);
intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

In the last line you're referring to `intent` rather than `intent1`. Have you got another field named `intent` somewhere which you haven't initialized?

Comment: yeah the intent was for the paramtres of the Onstart of the service  @Override
 public void onStart (Intent intent, int startId) {
  Log.d("ParseFunction", ">>>Started()"); 
  if (!mydata.equals("")){

Comment: my mistake, it should be intent1 but still the problem lies :-(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Intent intent1= new Intent (this, Test.class);
```

try:

```
Intent intent1= new Intent (getApplicationContext(), Test.class);
```

If that doesn't work, try without adding the flags.

However, keep in mind you should not start an Activity from a service or interact with the UI.

Comment: i've tried but still having the same error. i wish i can do otherwise because the thing is that i have a server on my android device waiting for image data, so once it has the data it passes it to the service parses it and then should start the activity which shows the image.

Comment: Then replace your service with an AsyncTask, which will handle all in the background like you want, but it has a method called OnPostExecute that will run in the UI thread where you can do whatever you want.

Comment: okido, i'm gonna try to learn more about AsyncTask... thx anyway :-)

Comment: Wait, on your activity your are not initializing the parser. You make ParseFunction parser;  and then parser.text, so parser is null.

Comment: how do i make it?? but still i remmber i've even tried to set a static the like result.settex("blalalalala ") it gives me the same error.

Comment: but the idea of Asynch task seems to be a good one. i'm going to read some tutorials :-)

Comment: Well, you should have something like parser = new ParserFunction().

Answer (score 0):

//here  your content is null

```
Intent intent1= new Intent (this, Test.class);
```

pass your application context here

```
Intent intent1= new Intent (mContent, Test.class);
```